# How to fetch td elements and pass to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have following HTML code:

```
<table>
   <th>Items</th><th>Rate</th><th>Quantity</th>
   <tr><td>Item A</td><td>20</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemA"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item B</td><td>10</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemB"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item C</td><td>30</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemC"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Total Price</td><td><input type="text" id="txtPrice"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

On the onblur event of textboxes, I want to call a javascript function which will multiply the quantity added by the user to the rate and display it in txtPrice textbox. But I am stuck in the logic that how should I pick the rate corresponding to the quantity entered.

For example: When I enter 2 in txtItemA textbox, 40 should get displayed in txtPrice textbox. Javascript function is simple it will just multiply rate with quantity entered and display it in txtPrice.

What should I do to get to fetch the associated rate against the quantity and pass it to javascript function?

Javascript function

```
function DisplayTotal(rate, quantity)
{
  document.getElementById('txtPrice').innerText = rate * quantity;
}
```

Comment: How is rate determined in the first place? Depending on whether there are a few set rates or infinite changes how you would go about solving this.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5jGep/1/

Comment: @DBS - For the time being, I am considering these as constants.

Comment: as an addition to Arun P Johny' solution, you can make it more performant by saving the result for each row in a special array, and then you need to recalculate only one particular row each time. But this is useful only for really big tables like that

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5jGep/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - yes, it is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/FeLKx/4/

**HTML :**

```
<table class="items">
    <thead>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="item">
            <td>Item A</td>
            <td class="rate">20</td>
            <td class="quantity">
                <input type="text" id="txtItemA" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td>Item B</td>
            <td class="rate">10</td>
            <td class="quantity">
                <input type="text" id="txtItemB" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td>Item C</td>
            <td class="rate">30</td>
            <td class="quantity">
                <input type="text" id="txtItemC" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Price</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtPrice" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.items .item .quantity input').blur(function () {
        var total = 0;

        $('.items .item').each(function(index, value) {
            var rate = $(this).find('.rate').text();
            var quantity = $(this).find('.quantity input').val();

            total += rate * quantity;
        });

        $('#txtPrice').val(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Give the elements in question a common class, say `class="quantity"`, so that they can easily be selected without listing out the ids or having too general a selector that also picks up the total price field, and then you can do this:

```
var $qtyFields = $('input.quantity').change(function() {
    var price = 0;
    $qtyFields.each(function() {
        price += this.value * $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
    });
    $("#txtPrice").val(price);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/95hje/

That is, loop through each field and multiply its value by the rate column in the same row. Finding a related element by using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get a common ancestor and then [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to traverse back down is a common pattern.

Note that the `*` operator will coerce its operands to be numeric, but the code I've shown doesn't actually do any validation so if the user enters non-numeric data the total will be `NaN`...

Answer (score 2):

A pure javascript solution (no JQuery) which will work even if you change the number of rows in your table and which handles the problem of invalid user input:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DisplayTotal(){
var num = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length-2;
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td"), total = 0, rate, quant;
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    rate = parseInt(tds[3*i+1].innerHTML);
    quant = parseInt(tds[3*i+2].firstChild.value);
        if(isNaN(quant)){
        continue;
        }
    total += rate*quant;
    }
document.getElementById("txtPrice").value = total;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr><th>Items</th><th>Rate</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Item A</td><td>20</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemA" onkeyup="DisplayTotal();"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item B</td><td>10</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemB" onkeyup="DisplayTotal();"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item C</td><td>30</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemC" onkeyup="DisplayTotal();"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Item D</td><td>50</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemD" onkeyup="DisplayTotal();"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Total Price</td><td><input type="text" id="txtPrice"></td></tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="DisplayTotal();">Get Total Price</button>
</body>
</html>
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p26EG/).

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup to add some classes to the input elements for easy selection

```
<table>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Rate</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Item A</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txtItem" id="txtItemA" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item B</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txtItem" id="txtItemB" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item C</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="txtItem" id="txtItemC" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total Price</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtPrice" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $items = $('.txtItem').change(function () {
        var total = 0;
        $items.each(function () {
            total += ($(this).data('price') * parseInt(this.value)) || 0;
        })
        $('#txtPrice').val(total)
    }).each(function () {
        //store the price of the item in data for easy access later
        $(this).data('price', parseInt($(this).parent().prev().text(), 10) || 0);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5jGep/)

Answer (score 1):

I have simpliest solution I guess  (without jQuery):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function DisplayTotal()
         {
            var quantity = 0, rate = 0, total=0;
            var i=0;
            do {
                var c = document.getElementById("txtItem" + i++);
                if (c) {
                    var r = c.parentNode.previousSibling;
                    if (c.value) {
                        quantity = parseFloat(c.value);
                        rate = parseFloat(r.innerHTML);
                        total += quantity * rate;
                    }
                }
            } while(c);
            document.getElementById('txtPrice').value = total.toFixed(2);
         }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
   <th>Items</th><th>Rate</th><th>Quantity</th>
   <tr><td>Item A</td><td>20</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItem0"  onblur="DisplayTotal()"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item B</td><td>10</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItem1" onblur="DisplayTotal()"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item C</td><td>30</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItem2" onblur="DisplayTotal()"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Total Price</td><td><input type="text" id="txtPrice"/></td></tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: what if I have random items?

Comment: what do you mean ? random rows or colons ?

Comment: you have made an array containing txtItemA...txtItemC. I could have more or less number of items in actual website.

Comment: change the id with a prefix like "txtItem" and a number (row). In the code use innerHTML than innerText.

Answer (score 1):

This is your html

```
<table>
   <th>Items</th><th>Rate</th><th>Quantity</th>
   <tr><td>Item A</td><td>20</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemA"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item B</td><td>10</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemB"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Item C</td><td>30</td><td><input type="text" id="txtItemC"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Total Price</td><td><input type="text" id="txtPrice"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

This will be your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').on('blur','td input[id^=txtItem]',function(){
        var fields = $('td input[id^=txtItem]');
        var total = 0;

        $.each(fields,function(index,value){
            var quantity = $(this).val();
            var rate = $(this).parent('td').prev('td').text();
            total += (quantity * rate);            
        });       
        $('#txtPrice').val(total);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/9yBrX/)

*On a note I strongly recommend you don't rely on javascript to finally charge the visitor as this can be easily changed to `0` using javascript*

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will also calculate all these values on server side.

Comment: Cool hope this answers your query

Answer (score 0):

See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/UFS97/1/

### HTML

```
<table id="invoice_tbl">
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <tr class="item">
            <td>Item A</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="item_price" id="txtItemA" value=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td>Item B</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="item_price" id="txtItemB"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
            <td>Item C</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="item_price" id="txtItemC" value=""/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Price</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtPrice"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



jQUery
---------------------------
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".item_price").blur(function(){
    total = 0.00;
    item_row = $("table#invoice_tbl").children('tbody').children("tr.item");
    item_row.each(function(){
        item_price = parseFloat($(this).children('td').eq(1).html());
        item_qty = parseInt($(this).children('td').eq(2).children('input').val());
        row_price = item_price*item_qty;
        if(!isNaN(row_price)){
            total +=row_price;
        }
    });
    $("#txtPrice").val(total);
});
});
```

See demo here http://jsfiddle.net/UFS97/1/